# Objects on top of nav, but nav should be on top of objects

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, css-float, css-position

I wrote this bit of code so that when a user is on my site, the navigation will follow them as they scroll. It works just fine, but there are few instances where objects will float on top of the nav and it will be hidden behind them. Here's a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/b24fgsf3/

You'll notice as you scroll the nav snaps to the top of the page at a certain point but the h1 tag is still visible over the top of the nav, and it hides the nav options briefly. Pretty annoying, and I think it's bad UX/UI. I've played around with the positions and a few other properties but I can't get it working correctly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the jQuery that I wrote. because I can't post anything without it apparently.

```
var num = 15;

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
    $('nav').addClass('fixed');
} else {
    $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
}
});
```

Comment: You need to set a `z-index` on the `nav`: https://jsfiddle.net/b24fgsf3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index: 1` to the `nav` to *stack* it on *top* of the `container` - see demo below:

```js
var num = 35;

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

```css
nav {
    background-color: white;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.hero {
  height: 200px;
}

.hero h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>Blah</li>
  <li>Blah</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hero">
    <h1>
    Blah Blah Blah 
    </h1>
  </div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elementum nullam neque consequat aenean, odio nec, nunc non magna a ut augue et. Dolor ut est quam pharetra, duis nulla id sed sed hendrerit, a lectus sed amet venenatis. Pulvinar ante magnis eros phasellus pellentesque sed, dapibus enim, quis ac morbi eros quis, in odio enim suspendisse nulla vestibulum wisi. Leo purus neque leo quam aliquet. Lobortis mi per felis eu. Tortor in nulla primis sit, maecenas velit, ligula pellentesque dis elementum, nunc mi erat mauris vitae blandit in. Phasellus amet pulvinar neque amet convallis, nulla fusce commodo aliquam augue, amet vitae et volutpat nam, nisl id nibh morbi et. Maecenas ultrices elit nibh. Doloremque massa amet vel lacus. Eros at suspendisse vulputate nulla condimentum, dignissim velit arcu, hac diam est, amet consequat id fermentum.
  
  Tempor eros elementum nullam nec ligula ligula. Curabitur mattis pede, lacus et eleifend, tellus sed ipsum cubilia enim, quam et fusce. Mi ligula, laoreet porttitor dignissim mauris consequat euismod ut, luctus ut, donec rhoncus mi eget. Et erat turpis pede quam donec. Integer augue, lacus metus dolor, magna condimentum. Libero leo ac varius, sodales faucibus lacus sed, pretium amet blandit sed mi neque curabitur, purus nunc sed egestas ut, quis id voluptate. Metus commodo enim, potenti orci vivamus, arcu dolor, accumsan euismod est aut sit non quam, sit leo et leo nam sociosqu non. Ante nunc integer vehicula. Nonummy dui viverra, elit morbi lectus feugiat. Ac fringilla cras tempor consectetuer consequat.

  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Dang, that was a simple fix. Thanks!

Comment: @BenGrzybowski cool, pls upvote / accept answer and close the question too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> SUGGESTION: you don't need to use javascript.

you can simply use `position: fixed;` on the `css` file.

and make the `z-index` a big value like: `99999` to come above of all other elements.

you should put the 'container' div, in the bottom of the navbar.

simply, use `relative` position for the 'container' elements.

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  top: 75px;
}
```

it will follow the users by scrolling:

```css
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
 
nav li{
  display:inline;
}

.hero {
  height: 200px;
}

.hero h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
  <li>Blah</li>
  <li>Blah</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="hero">
    <h1>
    Blah Blah Blah 
    </h1>
  </div>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elementum nullam neque consequat aenean, odio nec, nunc non magna a ut augue et. Dolor ut est quam pharetra, duis nulla id sed sed hendrerit, a lectus sed amet venenatis. Pulvinar ante magnis eros phasellus pellentesque sed, dapibus enim, quis ac morbi eros quis, in odio enim suspendisse nulla vestibulum wisi. Leo purus neque leo quam aliquet. Lobortis mi per felis eu. Tortor in nulla primis sit, maecenas velit, ligula pellentesque dis elementum, nunc mi erat mauris vitae blandit in. Phasellus amet pulvinar neque amet convallis, nulla fusce commodo aliquam augue, amet vitae et volutpat nam, nisl id nibh morbi et. Maecenas ultrices elit nibh. Doloremque massa amet vel lacus. Eros at suspendisse vulputate nulla condimentum, dignissim velit arcu, hac diam est, amet consequat id fermentum.
  
  Tempor eros elementum nullam nec ligula ligula. Curabitur mattis pede, lacus et eleifend, tellus sed ipsum cubilia enim, quam et fusce. Mi ligula, laoreet porttitor dignissim mauris consequat euismod ut, luctus ut, donec rhoncus mi eget. Et erat turpis pede quam donec. Integer augue, lacus metus dolor, magna condimentum. Libero leo ac varius, sodales faucibus lacus sed, pretium amet blandit sed mi neque curabitur, purus nunc sed egestas ut, quis id voluptate. Metus commodo enim, potenti orci vivamus, arcu dolor, accumsan euismod est aut sit non quam, sit leo et leo nam sociosqu non. Ante nunc integer vehicula. Nonummy dui viverra, elit morbi lectus feugiat. Ac fringilla cras tempor consectetuer consequat.

  </p>
  
    <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elementum nullam neque consequat aenean, odio nec, nunc non magna a ut augue et. Dolor ut est quam pharetra, duis nulla id sed sed hendrerit, a lectus sed amet venenatis. Pulvinar ante magnis eros phasellus pellentesque sed, dapibus enim, quis ac morbi eros quis, in odio enim suspendisse nulla vestibulum wisi. Leo purus neque leo quam aliquet. Lobortis mi per felis eu. Tortor in nulla primis sit, maecenas velit, ligula pellentesque dis elementum, nunc mi erat mauris vitae blandit in. Phasellus amet pulvinar neque amet convallis, nulla fusce commodo aliquam augue, amet vitae et volutpat nam, nisl id nibh morbi et. Maecenas ultrices elit nibh. Doloremque massa amet vel lacus. Eros at suspendisse vulputate nulla condimentum, dignissim velit arcu, hac diam est, amet consequat id fermentum.
  
  Tempor eros elementum nullam nec ligula ligula. Curabitur mattis pede, lacus et eleifend, tellus sed ipsum cubilia enim, quam et fusce. Mi ligula, laoreet porttitor dignissim mauris consequat euismod ut, luctus ut, donec rhoncus mi eget. Et erat turpis pede quam donec. Integer augue, lacus metus dolor, magna condimentum. Libero leo ac varius, sodales faucibus lacus sed, pretium amet blandit sed mi neque curabitur, purus nunc sed egestas ut, quis id voluptate. Metus commodo enim, potenti orci vivamus, arcu dolor, accumsan euismod est aut sit non quam, sit leo et leo nam sociosqu non. Ante nunc integer vehicula. Nonummy dui viverra, elit morbi lectus feugiat. Ac fringilla cras te
</div>
```

Comment: hey this works great, but my nav, isn't positioned at the top of the page as in the example, there's a few other differences as well, but my biggest issue was the text floating on top of the nav. Thanks for the solution though!